# Screwturn wiki searchable attachments

Tags: attachment, screwturn

I'm trying to set up a wiki for internal usage, and one of the key requirements is that attachments to wiki pages are searchable, which appears to be the sticking point of many other simple wikis.

Screwturn wiki seems to tick all the boxes, and even details in its most recent release notes (I have version 3.0.5.600 downloaded) that attachments are searchable, but this doesn't appear to be the case when I've been creating new pages with attachments. The text within the page is easily searchable; but nothing within even the .txt test attachments I've been adding is coming up on my internal searches.

I've played around with the permissions within the wiki (but I don't think this should be the problem as I'm logged in as the administrator, which surely should have all permissions granted), trawled through all the information I can find on screwturn's website & done extensive googling of this problem, but I couldn't find anyone who has had the same problem. Screwturns forum (now offline) directed me here, but I couldn't see anything on previous screwturn-related posts to help.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious? Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a v4 feature try downloading the alpha.  If you have problems feel free to ask questions / submit bugs on http://stw.codeplex.com